# UIView with UITableView and UIGestureRecognizer stops Gesture-Recognizing suddenly

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

My App has a view containing a `UITableView`. I added a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the view.
I use the GestureRecognizer for adjusting the TableViews width.

When the TableView´s width is adjusted, the cells within the table are also autoresized.

First this works very well. - After some resizes suddenly the GestureRecognizer doesn´t fire anymore. Within another view-region (other than the tableView) the GestureRecognizer still works fine.

Do I rotate the device, the GestureRecognizer starts working again for a while.

I have the same situation with a `UICollectionView` instead of the TableView - there works everything fine.

Any hints for solving the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out following approach, which works fine for me.

I added the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`-Protocol to my ViewController and added the following function:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```